# matplotlib and tkinter, help removing old plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So I have a simple tkinter GUI that I am using to help display plots. I have buttons that call functions like the below plot_record() which is suppose to update a plot. This all works fine, however whenever I go to close my program, it takes a bit to close. If I update the plot a lot (like 20 or 30 times) it takes a very long time to close.

I believe that I am not correctly clearing/closing my old plots whenever I update them. The goal of the below function is to remove the previous plots contents and update with new data.

Am I missing something?

```py
import tkinter  as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,  
NavigationToolbar2Tk) 

import numpy as np
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("My Test Program")
def plot_record():
    for _ in range(0,5):
        #define base address in HRT for where recorder data is stored, hex values
        base = [0, 800, 1000, 1800, 2000, 2800, 3000, 3800]
        #dummy data
        y=[]
        for i in range(0,10):
            y.append(1)
        for i in range(11,199):
            y.append(np.exp(-.01*(i-10))+np.random.rand()/10)
        
        fig3 = plt.figure(dpi=30)
        fig3.clear()
        plt.close(fig3)
        plot3 = fig3.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
        plot3.plot(y)
        plot3.set_xscale('linear')
        plot3.set_title('Recorder: ARC CHN'+str(0))
        # creating the Tkinter canvas containing the Matplotlib figure 
        canvas3 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig3, frame4) 
        canvas3.draw()
        # placing the canvas on the Tkinter window 
        canvas3.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')


#======================================================
#   FRAME 4
#======================================================
frame4 = tk.Frame(master=window, width=180, height=1000)
frame4.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)

#run plot once so that the plot will be above the button
plot_record();
# button that displays the plot 
arc_record = tk.Button(master = frame4,  
                     command = plot_record, 
                     height = 2,  
                     width = 20,
                     bg="gray",
                     fg="black",
                     text = "Fetch ARC Trip Record") 

# place the buttons 
arc_record.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
#starts the loop which allows this program to execute commands/events
#based on the users inputs
window.mainloop()
```

UPDATE: I have updated my code to be a 'minimally reproducible version'
when you run this, you should see a plot come up with a button. When you click the button it will update the plot. Note, I nested this plot in a for loop to help exaggerate my point.

1. if you update the plot once or twice and close the program, it closes fine.
2. if you update the plot 20+ times, the program takes a much longer time to close.

This seems to indicate that my plot clear/close is not actually clearing or closing the plot and is thus leaving some artifact. Is there a better way to clean up the old plots?

Thanks again :)

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code. And also you have `;` in your code.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I updated my code and removed my ';'. Thanks agian.

Comment: Hi @ Jakub Szlaur, were you able to run my modified code? I modified it to be minimally reproducible. I probably should have done that from the start.  Thanks again.